# Angular ngModel not updating when setting variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 4 and Typescript, I have a table of `<select>`s in my template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasksDetails">
    <td>{{task.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="task.uiMetadata.worker">
            <option value="">Select worker</option>
            <option *ngFor="let worker of workers" [value]="worker.resource.id">{{worker.resource.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Within another component I am able to add/remove to the workers list and it is output to a `Subject` which this component subscribes to:

```
this.workerRemoved.subscribe(worker => {
    _each(this.tasksDetails, taskTemplate => {
        if (taskTemplate.uiMetadata.worker === member.resourceId) {
            taskTemplate.uiMetadata.worker = '';
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that while the subscription updates the field in the variable, ngModel is not picking up the change and reflecting it in the UI.

[image: Chrome DevTools output]

So we end up with the situation where `ng-reflect-model` is showing "11", the worker variable is an empty string, and the select shows as blank because the "11" option has been removed.

How do I get Angular to keep the model in sync with the change I made in the subscription? I have tried wrapping it in an `NgZone.run()` and also calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` but neither would update the `ng-reflect-model` value.

[Here is a Plunker reproducing the error](https://embed.plnkr.co/TMyLwBT6uHpDTxvIpynE/)

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @echonax added link to Plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/SGbhsySRZAxWgWuANCwC?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui you should provide it as an answer so that OP can accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to yurzui pointing me in the right direction:

```
if (taskTemplate.uiMetadata.worker === member.resourceId) {
```

changes to

```
if (+taskTemplate.uiMetadata.worker === +member.resourceId) {
```

So that the strict equality is comparing numbers. The form input was converting the value into a string. Sometimes the easy ones can get ya.